# Store startup database changes through hibernate into a sql file

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, flyway

I have a complex startup import logic when starting up a spring boot server. In this startup process the database is filled with inital data structures which cannot be written directly in flyway or liquibase.

How can I store all database modifications of hibernate to a sql file. This file can then be used as a basline version.

I found no easy way to dump all sql modifications to a file from one specified moment to another specified moment.

Comment: Why flyway or liquibase is not an option? Because of the migration nature, or some other reason? What do you mean exactly with “cannot be written directly”?

Comment: I read the initial data from a json file but I have to make some business logic before i can put it into the database. Therefore I cannot directly write it a sql inserts.